# Read and Modify data in web.config asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I implemented access restriction for my asp.net website using the below code in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  </authentication>    
<authorization>
  <allow users="na\user1, phil\user2, so on" />
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

There are few admin users for whom I should provide an interface (a web page or a modalpopup) where they can see the current users, remove users or add users to access this site. Now I want to know

1) How to find the current users programmatically  i.e. the value of users attribute.

I got it worked out by using below code from [asp.net How do I reference authorized users hard coded in web.config in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990606/asp-net-how-do-i-reference-authorized-users-hard-coded-in-web-config-in-my-code?rq=1)

```
AuthorizationSection configSection =
  (AuthorizationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authorization");

    var users = new List<string>();

    var rules = configSection.Rules;

    foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
    {
        if (rule.Action == AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow)
        {
            foreach (string user in rule.Users)
            {
                if (!users.Contains(user))
                {
                    users.Add(user);

                }
            }

        }
        //rule.Users.Add("phil\user3");
        //rule.Users.Remove("phil\\user2");
    }
```

2) How to update web.config by removing or adding users when the site is running?

I tried adding and removing users using the commented lines from the above code but that didn't work.

Where I am wrong in that code? As I said I need to add or remove users in the web.config on the fly so if anyone can provide me some code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there. Please, check out http://forums.asp.net/t/1061722.aspx/1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime.

Comment: @AndreCalil thanks for the reply Calil..but I am afraid those links will only be useful for adding or modifying key value pairs inside AppSettings section.

Comment: I don't think so. Check this MSDN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx